# Filter a vector and return the 'n'th element

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I want to write a function that evaluates lazily and returns the `n`th element of a filtered vector. I am interested in the first or second element in the vector most of the times. So I don't want to filter the entire list and then find the `n`th element.

I am learning to use Boost and if there is a simple solution using Boost it would be highly instructive.

```
int main() {

    double x[] = {10, 12.5, 12.9, 13.7, 50.07};
    size_t length = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
    std::vector<double> vx(x, x+length);

    // Need a function to filter out elements less than 11 and return the 2nd
    // element greater than 11 (here 12.9) and return without evaluating 13.7 and 50.07


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your array always sorted ? And do you want elements strictly superior to 11 ?

Comment: @fjardon Not always sorted. Need greater or equal to 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in one of the first elements I would naively suggest something like this:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator element(size_t n, const std::vector<double>& vec) {
    std::vector<double>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    size_t found = 0;
    while (found != n && it != vec.end()) {
        if (*(it++) >= 11) ++found;
    }
    return it;
}
```

I has a linear complexity but exits as soon as the desired match is found.

Comment: Iterator `it` needs to incremented in the `while` loop. Adding `++it` at the end of the `while` loop suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)

```
float n=11.f;
auto it =std::partition(vx.begin(), vx.end(), 
                       [n](const double & p){ return p <n;});

 it++; //Second element
 if( it!= vx.end())
    std::cout<<"Element :"<<*it<<std::endl;
```

See [**here**](http://ideone.com/OLkFon)

Comment: I would like to parameterize filtering and the `n`th element I return.

Comment: @Anand see updated answer, you can put this in a function and return `it` as `std::vector<double>::iterator`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to use boost but this is what I would use:

```
int binarySearch(int whatToSearch){
    //recursive binary search 
    if value is found 
        return index
    else //not found
        return -index-1; //-index+1 will give you the place to insert that element    
}
```

Then I would get the second element after returned index if it exists.

Here is the code for binary search that I use

```
int mybinary_search(string array[],int first,int last, string search_key){
    int index;

    if (first > last)
        index = -first-1;

    else{
        int mid = (first + last)/2;

        if (search_key == array[mid])
            return mid;
        else if (search_key < array[mid])
        index = mybinary_search(array,first, mid-1, search_key);
        else
            index = mybinary_search(array, mid+1, last, search_key);

    } // end if
    return index;
}

double findAskedValue(int value){
    double x[] = {10, 12.5, 12.9, 13.7, 50.07};
    size_t length = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);

    int index = mybinarySearch(x,0,length, 11);
    if(index >= 0)
         cout << "value I'm searching for " << x[index+2] << endl;
    else
         cout << "value I'm searching for " << x[(-index-1)+2] << endl;
     //instead of cout's you can do what ever you want using that index
}
```

One little explanation: you are going to call findAskedValue(val) and it will return you a value. **If value > 0, then the element exist in the list, and index+2 is the location of the value you are searching for, else (-index-1) is the position where to insert that element. -index-1 + 2 is going to give you the second greater element.**

The complexity of that is `O(log(n))`